# Difference between int and double

Tags: java, integer, double

Why would anyone use *int* instead of *double*?

It seems to be that double is much more flexible than *int*.

Comment: *All* the other (visible) questions from the OP is about Java (some were untagged), so Java can be presumed.

Comment: (The OP has left the building - *"Last seen more than 7 years ago "*.)

Answer (score 33):

`int` and `double` have different semantics. Consider division. `1/2` is `0`, `1.0/2.0` is `0.5`. In any given situation, one of those answers will be right and the other wrong.

That said, there are programming languages, such as JavaScript, in which 64-bit float is the only numeric data type. You have to explicitly truncate some division results to get the same semantics as Java `int`. Languages such as Java that support integer types make truncation automatic for integer variables.

In addition to having different semantics from `double`, `int` arithmetic is generally faster, and the smaller size (32 bits vs. 64 bits) leads to more efficient use of caches and data transfer bandwidth.

Answer (score 9):

Operations on integers are exact. `double` is a floating point data type, and floating point operations are approximate whenever there's a fraction.

`double` also takes up twice as much space as `int` in many implementations (e.g. most 32-bit systems) .

Comment: Afaik double and int are both 64bit on 64bit architectures.

Comment: I clarified that it's most 32-bit systems.

Comment: Perfect! Keep in mind int as a C datatype can be 16bit on a 32bit machine!

Answer (score 1):

int is a binary representation of a whole number, double is a double-precision floating point number.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:**

`int` uses up four bytes of memory (and it *cannot* contain a decimal), and `double` uses eight bytes of memory. There are just different tools for different purposes.

Comment: You will find that this is dependend on the environment and the language. c does not define the size of the int.

Comment: True. Calling `sizeof(int)` is probably your best bet to be sure. But do you know if 2 byte integers exist anywhere now?

Comment: Yes, C integers on the Arduino ( a popular electronics prototyping platform ) are 16 bits.