# How do I make Java display a display a quotient and a remainder?

Tags: java

I can only seem to get it to display the quotient and the decimal. For example if I divide 9 by 2, I will get 4.5. However, I would like to get it to be 4r 1.  My current code is 
 import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Convert{   

 public static void main(String [] args){      
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);      

  double dividend;      
  double divisor;      
  double quotient;           

  System.out.print("Enter the dividend ");    
  dividend = reader.nextDouble();     

  System.out.print("Enter the divisor ");       
  divisor = reader.nextDouble();    

  quotient = dividend/divisor;          

  System.out.print("The quotient is ");    
  System.out.println(quotient);       
 } 
}
```

Comment: There isn't a remainder when you divide by a double.

Comment: You need to calculate it explicitly.

Comment: I appreciate the timely comeback ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: you are using the wrong *types* then.

It seems that you want to operate on *whole* numbers.

Then don't use *floating point* numbers, but types such as int or long.

Because different types imply different semantics for the corresponding operations, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555019/difference-between-int-and-double) for example. Beyond that, you then want to look into the % or *modulo* operator (see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)).

Comment: the basic is enough :)

Comment: Dividing with whole-number types still won't return a remainder - just the rounded result of dividing with decimal types.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam Correct, I could have been more precise about that. I enhanced my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use a decimal type like `float` or `double`, use a whole-number type like `int` or `long`. Second off, to get a reminder, you'll need to use the modulus operator (`%`). It works like so:

`int i = 5 % 2;` equals 1.

`int i = 13 % 7;` equals 6.

Comment: No point in using `short`: shorts are widened to (at least) `int` when you divide them.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2): it's the "binary numeric promotion" bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could change all values to an `int`

Then also get the remainder by using the modulus operator (`%`)

```
int dividend;
int divisor;
int quotient;
int remainder;
String remainderResult;

System.out.print("Enter the dividend ");
dividend = reader.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the divisor ");
divisor = reader.nextInt();

quotient = dividend / divisor;
remainder = dividend % divisor;

remainderResult = (remainder != 0) ? ", remainder " + remainder : "";

System.out.println("The quotient is " + quotient + remainderResult);
```